# Scipy ImportError: No module named transform

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-spatial

I'm using a python script within ROS. Ros uses python 2.7 and the version of scipy that I'm using is 0.19.1.
The following error is reported:

`from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
    ImportError: No module named transform`

Comment: `Rotation` was added in scipy 1.2.0.  You'll need to upgrade scipy to use it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Working on python 3.7.3. Make sure it's available on 2.7

Comment: How to correct it for older python? I'm a newbie in python

Comment: You can't install python 3.7 ?

Comment: Try to import math or something else because i tried with 2.7 and it's working on online IDE

Comment: Ros automatically uses python2.7. Thank you I'll try another function

Comment: Downvoted, sorry. What matters is the scipy vwrsion. Python version is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Try upgrading scipy to version 1.2.0:

```
pip install scipy==1.2.0
```